# Dockerfile to answer Y & N for single command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My dockerfile has below,

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt install -y aptitude
RUN aptitude -f install python-dev
```

Manual `aptitude -f install python-dev` installation inside the container prompts option to choose `n` and `Y`, Same as follows.

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpython-dev{a} libpython-stdlib{a} python{a} python-dev python-minimal{a}
0 packages upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 182 kB of archives. After unpacking 898 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython2-stdlib : Breaks: libpython-stdlib (< 2.7.15-2) but 2.7.11-1 is to be installed
 python2 : Breaks: python (< 2.7.15-2) but 2.7.11-1 is to be installed
 python2-minimal : Breaks: python-minimal (< 2.7.15-2) but 2.7.11-1 is to be installed
 python-is-python2 : Breaks: python but 2.7.11-1 is to be installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libpython-stdlib [Not Installed]
2)     python [Not Installed]
3)     python-dev [Not Installed]
4)     python-minimal [Not Installed]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Remove the following packages:
1)      libpython2-stdlib [2.7.17-2ubuntu4 (focal, now)]
2)      mic [0.28.6 (now)]
3)      python-is-python2 [2.7.17-4 (focal, now)]
4)      python-pycurl [7.43.0.2-1ubuntu5 (focal, now)]
5)      python-pyparsing [2.4.6-1 (focal, now)]
6)      python-rpm [4.14.2.1+dfsg1-1build2 (focal, now)]
7)      python-urlgrabber [3.9.1-4ubuntu3 (now)]
8)      python2 [2.7.17-2ubuntu4 (focal, now)]
9)      python2-minimal [2.7.17-2ubuntu4 (focal, now)]

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:
10)     python2-minimal recommends python2


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
```

My goal is to build the docker image through dockerfile. So in `Dockerfile` how to respond the `n` and `y` prompts automatically for the above case? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: better look for a headless installation.

Comment: can you share one example which would proceed through `dockerfile`.

Comment: I dont know, you need to research yourself. I can just give you the keyword to look for. *Headless* means without human interaction.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `apt` or `aptitude` in a Dockerfile.  Since this apparent conflict is just over a recommendation, `apt-get install --no-install-recommends` will not consider this.  More generally I'd recommend trying to statically resolve conflicts like this in your Dockerfile and `apt-get install`ing a consistent set of packages rather than trying to answer these interactive prompts.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable interactive prompting from `apt` by setting the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` environment variable to `noninteractive`. This is documented in the [`debconf(7)` man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man7/debconf.7.html). That would look something like:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y python-dev
```

Comment: In mycase `apt install -y python-dev` doesn't work, it shows lot of dependency errors. Hence want to go through `aptitude -f install python-dev` and its selections.

Comment: Fortunately that doesn't change the nature of this answer. You can set `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` before calling `aptitude` as well.

Comment: ...although having said that, the Dockerfile included in my answer builds without errors or dependency problems. I think perhaps the fact that you forgot to call `apt update` may be the real source of your problem.

Comment: Ok, we will try and come back.

Comment: `RUN apt update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive aptitude -f install python-dev` doesn't work.

Comment: You're forgetting to pass `-y` to aptitude: `aptitude -fy install python-dev`